# Rails 4 - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, nomethoderror

I am using the PaperClip, AWS, and s3_direct_upload gems to upload simple images.  I am following this tutorial here: http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

The file is uploaded successfully to S3, but during post-processing, I get the following error:

```
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 973ms

  NoMethodError (undefined method `upload_file_name=' for #<Choice:0x007f9ea60e02d0>):
   app/models/choice.rb:60:in `set_upload_attributes'
   app/controllers/choices_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

Here is what my model ("Choice") looks like, where `upload_file_name` should be defined: https://gist.github.com/dodinas/7237377

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks very much!

Comment: You're code looks nice and clean, good style. Probably you didn't run migrations in the production environment or restart the server afterwards to pick up the column changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run your migrations. You would get that error if the column doesnt exist on the table in the database.

Comment: It turns out that some of my code was using the wrong method, e.g., line 60 should have been `self.picture_file_name` NOT `self.upload_filename`.  Your post got me looking into the column names.  Thanks.